# Is it "GPL License" or "GPL license"?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

Every time I write *GPL license* the spelling checker of my Mac OS X keeps to underline *license* in green; if I write *GPL License*, the spelling checker doesn't underline *License*.
When I hover the mouse over the word, the Mac shows a tool tip with the following sentence:

> The word *license* may not agree with the rest of the sentence.

This happens whatever I write, even if I write *The GPL license is commonly used.*

If I write *the GPL Licence is commonly used*, the word *Licence* is underlined in red, and I get the suggestion to replace it with *License* or *Licensee*.
The same happens if I use *licence*.

What I am  doing wrong?

PS: My Mac is set to use the American English as default language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, "GPL" is a three letter acronym for GNU [General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatDoesGPLStandFor). (Note the AmE spelling.)

> “GPL” stands for “General Public License”. The most widespread such license is the GNU General Public License, or GNU GPL for short. This can be further shortened to “GPL”, when it is understood that the GNU GPL is the one intended.

By the way, "GPL License" (with or without the capital L) is an example of the self referentially humorous [RAS Syndrome:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome)

> the redundant use of one or more of the words that make up an acronym or initialism with the abbreviation itself, thus in effect repeating one or more words

Be aware that some people abhor RAS syndrome so

> In writing intended to persuade, impress, or avoid criticism, the writer is wise to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong spelling of license.

You should use licence, with a c, as that's a noun and the correct spelling in this context. License with an s is a verb as in: "We must license you to drive." Note this is for British English; in US English *license* is the noun spelling as well.

As for capitalisation, spell-checkers usually automatically assume anything with a capital letter is a proper noun and thus outside their remit, otherwise they'd annoyingly underline most people's names.

Comment: 1) In US English, the noun is spelled with an S. 2) In your example, *license* is actually a noun, not a verb.

Comment: You're right! Edited. As for the US version, Kiamlaluno, not sure where you're from, but if you're using British English go with what I suggested, if you're using US English check your Mac's dictionary language.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still unhappy with the "you should use licence, with a c" part, *especially* in light of the spelling on [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), and [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22gpl+license%22).

Comment: In British English, licence refers to a document giving permission. So you'd be licensed to drive, but have a driver's licence. Therefore it would be a GPL licence in British English. Answer edited to that effect.

Comment: Using the US spelling in British English would seem to me to be correct if it was part of a proper name. But the 'L' in 'GPL' stands for 'Licence', so if you write 'GPL licence' the second 'licence' appears to be a clarification and not part of the proper name of the licence. If you were to expand out 'GNU Public License' then it would seem appropriate to use the spelling quoted on gnu.org and not the locally correct one.

Comment: @Tim: But 'Public License' isn't a proper name, any more than 'Driver's Licence' is.

Comment: I apologize for not reporting the exact details in my question. First, the word is highlighted in green and not in red as I previously said; then, the default language I set on my Mac is American English.

Comment: If I write _My name is Licence_, the spelling checker underlines _License_ in red, and suggests me to replace the word with _License_ or _Licensee_; the same happens with Firefox (which uses a different spelling checker) that suggests me to use _License_. It doesn't seem true that spelling checkers ignore words in capital case.

Comment: It doesn't in mine; clearly all spell-checkers aren't created equal. A green underline suggests an error in grammar rather than spelling.

Comment: @ElendilTheTail: "The GNU General Public License", in this context, is a proper name for a specific licence, as defined by the GNU foundation. It isn't a noun phrase referring to all licences that are both general and public.